# ggplot exponential smooth with tuning parameter inside exp

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggplot provides various "smoothing methods" or "formulas" that determine the form of the trend line. However it is unclear to me how the parameters of the formula are specified and how I can get the exponential formula to fit my data. In other words how to tell ggplot that it should fit the parameter inside the exp.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(65,53,41,32,28,26,23,19))
df$y <- c(4,3,2,8,12,8,20,15)

   x  y
1 65  4
2 53  3
3 41  2
4 32  8
5 28 12
6 26  8
7 23 20
8 19 15
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", se=FALSE, color="black", formula = y ~ exp(x)) +
  geom_point()

p
```

Problematic fit:

[image]

However if the parameter inside the exponential is fit then the form of the trend line becomes reasonable:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", se=FALSE, color="black", formula = y ~ exp(-0.09 * x)) +
  geom_point()

p
```

[image]

Comment: You can pass params through to `glm` via `method.args`, e.g. `ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "glm", formula = y ~ x, method.args = list(family = gaussian(link = 'log'))) +
    geom_point()`, if that's what you're after

Comment: @alistaire just wondering why "log"? I need "y~ exp(x)". Is the link considering x's relation to y instead of y's relation to x? Is that coming from args?

Comment: Yep, you can think of the link function as a transformation of y. That's useful here because `glm` will fit a coefficient in front of the whole x term `coef * exp(x)` instead of inside: `exp(coef * x)` like you want. But if you take the log of both sides of the equation, `log(y) ~ x`, and now the coefficient on x will be fit properly, and the results will be equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach with method `nls` instead of `glm`.

You can pass additional parameters to `nls` with a list supplied in `method.args =`. Here we define starting values for the `a` and `r` coefficients to be fit from.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "nls", se = FALSE,
              formula = y ~ a * exp(r * x),
              method.args = list(start = c(a = 10, r = -0.01)),
              color = "black") +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

As discussed in the comments, the best way to get the coefficients on the graph is by fitting the model outside the `ggplot` call.

```
model.coeff <- coef(nls( y ~ a * exp(r * x), data = df, start = c(a = 50, r = -0.04)))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "nls", se = FALSE,
              formula = y ~ a * exp(r * x),
              method.args = list(start = c(a = 50, r = -0.04)),
              color = "black") +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(x = 40, y = 15,
            label = as.expression(substitute(italic(y) == a %.% italic(e)^(r %.% x),
                                             list(a = format(unname(model.coeff["a"]),digits = 3),
                                                  r = format(unname(model.coeff["r"]),digits = 3)))),
            parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: How could I get the equation ( final a and r) and R_squared?

Comment: Unfortunately, other than some really complicated hacks, there is no way to get the values out of the fitted model created by geom_smooth. The easiest way is to fit the model twice. Once before you call ggplot, and once with geom_smooth.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a method for getting the equation onto the graph.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, to pass additional parameters to the function passed to the `method` param of `geom_smooth`, you can pass a list of named parameters to `method.args`.

Secondly, the problem you're seeing is that `glm` is placing the coefficient in front of the whole term: `y ~ coef * exp(x)` instead of inside: `y ~ exp(coef * x)` like you want. You could use optimization to solve the latter outside of `glm`, but you can fit it into the GLM paradigm by a transformation: a log link. This works because it's like taking the equation you want to fit, `y = exp(coef * x)`, and taking the log of both sides, so you're now fitting `log(y) = coef * x`, which is equivalent to what you want to fit and works with the GLM paradigm. (This ignores the intercept. It also ends up in transformed link units, but it's easy enough to convert back if you like.)

You can run this outside of ggplot to see what the models look like:

```r
df <- data.frame(
    x = c(65,53,41,32,28,26,23,19), 
    y <- c(4,3,2,8,12,8,20,15)
)

bad_model <- glm(y ~ exp(x), family = gaussian(link = 'identity'), data = df)
good_model <- glm(y ~ x, family = gaussian(link = 'log'), data = df)

# this is bad
summary(bad_model)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = y ~ exp(x), family = gaussian(link = "identity"), 
#>     data = df)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -7.7143  -2.9643  -0.8571   3.0357  10.2857  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
#> (Intercept)  9.714e+00  2.437e+00   3.986  0.00723 **
#> exp(x)      -3.372e-28  4.067e-28  -0.829  0.43881   
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 41.57135)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 278.00  on 7  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 249.43  on 6  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 56.221
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2

# this is better
summary(good_model)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = y ~ x, family = gaussian(link = "log"), data = df)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
#> -3.745  -2.600   0.046   1.812   6.080  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  3.93579    0.51361   7.663 0.000258 ***
#> x           -0.05663    0.02054  -2.757 0.032997 *  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 12.6906)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 278.000  on 7  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance:  76.143  on 6  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 46.728
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

From here, you can reproduce what `geom_smooth` is going to do: make a sequence of x values across the domain and use the predictions as the y values for the line:

```r
# new data is a sequence across the domain of the model
new_df <- data.frame(x = seq(min(df$x), max(df$x), length = 501))

# `type = 'response'` because we want values for y back in y units
new_df$bad_pred <- predict(bad_model, newdata = new_df, type = 'response')
new_df$good_pred <- predict(good_model, newdata = new_df, type = 'response')

library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

new_df %>% 
    # reshape to long form for ggplot
    gather(model, y, contains('pred')) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color = model)) + 
    # plot original points on top
    geom_point(data = df)
```

[image: glm predictions plot]

Of course, it's a lot easier to let ggplot handle all that for you:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_smooth(
        method = 'glm', 
        formula = y ~ x, 
        method.args = list(family = gaussian(link = 'log'))
    ) + 
    geom_point()
```

[image: glm smooth with log link]